# temperature pressure valve leaking

Tags: water-tank

I just change my pressure relief valve due to the previous valve dripping.  This was suggested by my plumber. The new one is also dripping. What could the problem be?

Comment: When you open the hot valve at your sink, do you notice a surge of water and then a reduction in pressure? This is a classic sign of high pressure in the system. The pressure builds as the heater heats the water, when you open the valve you release the pressure.  For a moment the water will come out at the higher pressure, but then will drop back down to the normal pressure.

Comment: What was your T&P valve attached to? Was it on a boiler or a water heater?

Answer (score 1):

The initial check would be to install a pressure gauge on a hose faucet and check to see if your relief device is opening because your supply pressure exceeds the pressure set-point of the relief valve.

[image]

Also check if it is a temperature sensing valve as well, and ensure that is within range. If it leaks but is within range, I would return it for a new one.

**Note** these valves are notorious for leaking once they have opened (manually or due to exceedance of setpoint), do not manually open the valve during handling or after installation. Also, on boilers/water heaters, most local codes require that the valve outlet is plumbed to an outdoor location.

Comment: Can you cite the code that says that the T&P valve has to be plumbed to the outdoors? I guess a drain eventually goes outdoors, but I don't think the code specifically "*outdoors*".

Comment: If it is connected to a drain, it needs to be secured so the pipe wont move an there needs to be a air gap (typically 1") between the end of the pipe and where the water would collect in the drain.

Comment: @tester101, the local inspector required that I pipe the T-P relief valve drain to the outside of the exterior wood-frame stucco cabinet where my water heater resides. I assumed it was common local code. After researching a bit I found **you are correct**, our municipal code adopts UPC which requires nothing of the sort. Oh well, I need to stay on good relations with my inspector (doughnuts & coffee for him when he comes).